# Unity 3d Invokerepeating for blinking Images

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, 3d, repeat

I am working on a car game project. I have made a UI Panel in which there are two UI Images (Left_Image and Right_Image). When I press "left" button then Left_Image starts blinking and when i press "right" button the Right_Image starts blinking. but what i want is that if Right_Image is already blinking and I press "left" button then Left_Image starts blink but Right_Images should be stopped. I have tried every trick but no luck. Please help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Indicators_UI : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject flash_right;
    public GameObject flash_left;

    public float interval;

    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("RightFlash", 0, interval);
        InvokeRepeating("LeftFlash", 0, interval);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis ("right") != 0) {

            if (!IsInvoking("RightFlash"))
                InvokeRepeating("RightFlash", 0.35f, 0.35f);
        } 
        else
        {
            CancelInvoke("RightFlash");
        }
        if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis ("left") != 0) {
            if (!IsInvoking("LeftFlash"))
                InvokeRepeating("LeftFlash", 0.35f, 0.35f);
        } 
        else
        {
            CancelInvoke("LeftFlash");
        }
    }

    void RightFlash()
    {
        if(flash_right.activeSelf)
            flash_right.SetActive(false);
        else
            flash_right.SetActive(true);
    }

    void LeftFlash()
    {
        if(flash_left.activeSelf)
            flash_left.SetActive(false);
        else
            flash_left.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just add a bool and have flashleft, flashright, and set and use them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In general **don't** use `InvokeRepeating` etc with `string`! It is not very maintainable to call methods via their names. If you want to use them at least rather use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) to be sure the name is not misspelled.

Then can't you just do

```
void Update ()
{
    if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis ("right") != 0) 
    {
        if (!IsInvoking(nameof(RightFlash)))
        {
            if(IsInvoking(nameof(LeftFlash)) CancelInvoke(nameof(LeftFlash));

            InvokeRepeating(nameof(RightFlash), 0.35f, 0.35f);
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        CancelInvoke(nameof(RightFlash));
    }

    if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis ("left") != 0) 
    {
        if (!IsInvoking(nameof(LeftFlash)))
        {
            if(IsInvoking(nameof(RightFlash)) CancelInvoke(nameof(RightFlash));

            InvokeRepeating(nameof(LeftFlash), 0.35f, 0.35f);
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        CancelInvoke(nameof(LeftFlash));
    }
}

// Btw: These you can implement way shorter this way ;)
void RightFlash()
{
    flash_right.SetActive(!flash_right.activeSelf);
}

void LeftFlash()
{
    flash_left.SetActive(!flash_left.activeSelf);
}
```

---

In your case I would actually rather use simple timers since you need the `Update` method anyway for getting the user input so why overcomplicating:

```
private float timerLeft;
private float timerRight;

void Update ()
{
    if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis ("right") != 0) 
    {
        timerRight -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timerRight <= 0)
        {
            timerRight = interval;

            RightFlash();
        }
    }
    // simply make them exclusive so only one button is handled at a time
    // if you press both at the same time right overrules
    else if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis ("left") != 0) 
    {
        timerLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timerLeft <= 0)
        {
            timerLeft = interval;

            LeftFlash();
        }
    } 
}

void RightFlash()
{
    flash_right.SetActive(!flash_right.activeSelf);
}

void LeftFlash()
{
    flash_left.SetActive(!flash_left.activeSelf);
}
```